# MS Access - Analyze table and remove duplicates

Tags: ms-access

I have large single table that 'tracks' books, their shelving, and the people who currently have them. I want to build a database for them that is easier to work with. I tried to use the 'Analyze Table' function, but since it is a flat table there are duplicate shelves and people when I do that and I am not sure how to remove the duplicates while maintaining the relationships across the books.

So basically the one table is currently:
ISBN, TITLE, AUTHOR, PURCHASE COST, PURCHASE DATE, FIRST NAME, LAST NAME, PHONE, OFFICE, AISLE, BOOKCASE, SHELF.
And I want to split it into three tables with their respective fields; BOOKS, PEOPLE, SHELVING

I tried to use the 'Analyze Table' function, but it doesnt seem to support a way to remove the duplicates while maintaining the relationships.

Comment: There is also a "Find Duplicates Query Wizard"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find duplicates in a table using Access SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458191/how-to-find-duplicates-in-a-table-using-access-sql)

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194959/remove-duplicate-records-ms-access-sql-microsoft

Comment: Apologies, but these responses are just for locating and removing duplicates. The issue is maintaining the relationships when removing the duplicates, not the actual removal itself.

Comment: For each new table use a make-table query grouped by target fields. For example, to create PEOPLES table : SELECT FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,PHONE,OFFICE INTO PEOPLES  FROM [old flat table] GROUP BY FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,PHONE,OFFICE and then add an ID column (autonumber, primary key) to it.

Comment: @Shahram Alemzadeh - Yes, I believe that is the best course. 

I started working on it yesterday, I had an issue where it was duplicating the book records but with different people. So I created some calculated fields for people and locations and I think that worked, allowing me to pull out unique book records while attaching a location and people ID to the book. Ill update the top when I am finished.